# Can this question be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closing

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55505/whats-the-south-west-rule-in-minecraft) question was closed as a not a real question. I had since edited the qestion and elaborated on why it was a real question. Is it possible to re-open the question, or is it still not fit the site?

Comment: I removed my downvote and voted to reopen.

Comment: [status-completed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is done.

[image]